I'm making a game like Bubble Shooter and being stuck in the shooting part
I have a shoot point called shooterPos on the scene. First time it is fine, bubble is shot from it. Butt on the second time, the bubble is shot from the targetPos to the shooterPos
Here is my code of the method:
i want to shoot all the bubbles from the shooterPos
createShotBubble(angle: number, direction: Vec2) {
        const bubbleNode = instantiate(this.bubblePrefab);
        const bubble = bubbleNode.getComponent(Bubble);
        bubbleNode.setPosition(new Vec3(this.shooterPos.x, this.shooterPos.y, 0)); // Set initial position to shooterPos
    
        this.node.addChild(bubbleNode); // Add the bubbleNode to the piecesLayer instead of the PlayerController node
    
        const targetPos = this.shooterPos.add(direction.normalize().multiplyScalar(this.shotSpeed));
        console.log('target: ', targetPos);
        tween(bubbleNode)
            .to(this.shotDuration, { position: new Vec3(targetPos.x, targetPos.y, 0) }, { easing: 'sineOut' })
            .call(() => {
                
                bubble.destroyBubble();
            })
            .start();
    }

